# ASP.net information event "Application compilation is starting"

Tags: asp.net, iis, events

We use MSMQ to capture all the event thrown by our asp.net site and store the data into our database.  Throughout the day, we can see the event id `1003` with `Title = "Application compilation is starting"` in our logging database.

However, we don't see the corresponding event `1004` which is `"Application compilation ends".`  I was wondering what could possibly cause this?  We deploy our site with the precompiled option (update allow) and we have a very high use of session object (bad I know!).  Do the message indicates our web app is restarting on its own?

Thanks,
Herman

Comment: Some thoughts - AppPool shutdown/restart? Config changes?  More detail required really.

Comment: The AppPool does not restart, it seems like ASP.net is only splitting out these message when a low volume page is being view (probably for the first time).  But I thought a pre-compiled website deployment would not need compiling?

Answer (score 0):

Try precompiling without allowing for update.  When you allow for update there is a second runtime compiliation as noted in the following article under `Precompling for Deployment and Update.`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/399f057w%28v=vs.85%29.aspx